# Can't Multiply Sequence by Non-Int Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
number_of_people = input("Enter number of people attending the picnic: ")
if number_of_people.isnumeric():

    number_of_donuts = input("Enter number of donuts each person will want: ")
    if number_of_donuts.isnumeric():

        min_box = (number_of_people * number_of_donuts ) // 12
        box_remainder = (number_of_people * number_of_donuts ) % 12
        if box_remainder != 0:
            min_box = min_box + 1

        print("Minimum boxes of donuts needed: ", min_box)

        donuts_left = (min_box * 12) - (number_of_people * number_of_donuts )
        print("Donuts left over:", donuts_left)

        if min_box <= 5:
            donut_cost = 8 * min_box
        elif min_box <= 20:
            donut_cost = 7.50 * min_box
        else:
            donut_cost = 6 * min_box

        print ("Donuts cost: ",format(donut_cost, '.2f'))

    else:
        print(number_of_donuts, "is not a valid number")

else:
    print (number_of_people, "is not a valid number")
```

I'm really confused. I want to be able to tell the person that they are entering a wrong input, but if I change the input to int(input. I wouldn't know how to notify the user if they aren't putting an int.

The error I receive 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: I think I was able to guess it, but for future reference, please include the rest of the error (especially the part that tells us which line it's on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the issue is on this line?

```
donuts_left = (min_box * 12) - (number_of_people * number_of_donuts )
```

I think the issue is that `number_of_people` and `number_of_donuts` are both strings, but you probably want to be dealing with numbers.

Try the below. (I added the `x = int(x)` lines to convert the `str`s to `int`s.)

```
number_of_people = input("Enter number of people attending the picnic: ")
if number_of_people.isnumeric():
    number_of_people = int(number_of_people)

    number_of_donuts = input("Enter number of donuts each person will want: ")
    if number_of_donuts.isnumeric():
        number_of_donuts = int(number_of_donuts)

        min_box = (number_of_people * number_of_donuts ) // 12
        box_remainder = (number_of_people * number_of_donuts ) % 12
        if box_remainder != 0:
            min_box = min_box + 1

        print("Minimum boxes of donuts needed: ", min_box)

        donuts_left = (min_box * 12) - (number_of_people * number_of_donuts )
        print("Donuts left over:", donuts_left)

        if min_box <= 5:
            donut_cost = 8 * min_box
        elif min_box <= 20:
            donut_cost = 7.50 * min_box
        else:
            donut_cost = 6 * min_box

        print ("Donuts cost: ",format(donut_cost, '.2f'))

    else:
        print(number_of_donuts, "is not a valid number")

else:
    print (number_of_people, "is not a valid number")
```

Comment: Usually best to just perform the `int` conversion and catch errors, not perform an `isnumeric` test, then convert. Even for simple cases, `isnumeric` is stricter than `int`; it won't accept negative numbers, leading or trailing whitespace (which `int` ignores seamlessly), etc. Obviously, the OP was using `isnumeric` testing, but since adding `int` conversions is needed anyway, `isnumeric` could be dropped. Not downvoting (minimizing changes from OPs code is fine), just mentioning it for the OP's benefit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Definitely agreed. (And you're right that I chose this path specifically to minimizing the changes to OP's code.)

Comment: @RanniRoscios I'm not sure what you're asking. I already added those lines to the code. I was just pointing out what I changed. (The third line of my version of the code is the first change.)